# Linq/EF Dynamic Group by with optional parameter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm facing a problem with my search/group function.

**Context**

I've a list of customer objects (Entity Framework Context) and I want to find all possible duplicates in this list. The criteria if an object is a duplicate should be dynamic. Let's say selectable by the UI.

**Model**

Let's assume the following parts as given.

My CustomerClass

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string SearchName { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Possible criteria for duplicates are: SearchName, Mail, Birthday and CardNumber.

The following function returns an appropriate result:

```
    public IList<Customer> GetPossibleDuplicates()
    {
        IList<Customer> list;

        list =
            (from s in this.Context.Customers
                group s by new
                           {
                               s.SearchName, 
                               s.CardNumber
                           }
                into g where g.Count() > 1 select g)
                .SelectMany(g => g)
                .OrderBy(o => o.SearchName)
                .ThenBy(c => c.Created)
                .ToList();


        return list;
    }
```

The problem I've is to make the group by statement "dynamic" so based on the selected creteria the grouping is made. Any suggestions for a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerable.GroupBy allows a parameter of IEqualityComparer. See [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534334(v=vs.100).aspx).

This comparer could be the dynamic part of the query. You state that the grouping is based on the selection criteria so this would give you:

```
public IList<Customer> GetPossibleDuplicates()
{
    var comparer = SomeMethodReturningAnEqualityComparerBasedOnSelectionCriteria();
    return this.Context.Customers
            .GroupBy(customer => customer, comparer)
            .SelectMany(g => g)
            .OrderBy(o => o.SearchName)
            .ThenBy(c => c.Created)
            .ToList();
}
```

The method returning the comparer would return `IEqualityComparer<Customer>`.

Comment: Thank you Andy! The hint leads to a better solution. But with IEqualityComparer I can only check for equaltiy for an in Memory Collection right? So with multiple thousends of customers doesn't seems to perform very well, right? (The this.Context is an Entity Framework Context)

Comment: You're right. My answer was for an in memory collection and I hadn't considered that this was Entity Framework. You may even get a run time error doing it this way when Entity Framework tries to convert it to a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about relying on a criteria built around [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)

```c#
Func<Customer, IComparable> criteria
```

and your query encapsulated in a method would look like this

```c#
public IList<Customer> FindByCriteria(Func<Customer, IComparable> criteria)
{
    var query = from customer in FindAll()
                group customer by criteria(customer)
                into groups
                where groups.Count() > 1
                from item in groups
                orderby item.SearchName, item.Created
                select item;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Then you can play around with your own data structure or even with [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

```c#
void Main()
{
    var repository = new Repository();

    //Find all
    repository.FindAll().Dump();

    // Find by mail
    var mail = new Func<Customer, IComparable>(customer =>
    {
        return Tuple.Create(customer.Mail);
    });
    repository
        .FindByCriteria(mail)
        .Dump();

    // Find by mail and card number
    var multi = new Func<Customer, IComparable>(customer =>
    {
        return Tuple.Create(customer.CardNumber, customer.Mail);
    });
    repository
        .FindByCriteria(multi)
        .Dump();
}
```

Where complete repository code is bellow

```c#
public class Repository
{
    public IList<Customer> FindByCriteria(Func<Customer, IComparable> criteria)
    {
        var query = from customer in FindAll()
                    group customer by criteria(customer)
                    into groupings
                    where groupings.Count() > 1
                    from grouping in groupings
                    orderby grouping.SearchName, grouping.Created
                    select grouping;

        return query.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> FindAll()
    {
        yield return new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = 1,
            SearchName = "John",
            CardNumber = "0000 0000 0000 0000 1",
            Mail = "john.doe@test.com",
        };

        yield return new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = 2,
            SearchName = "Jim",
            CardNumber = "0000 0000 0000 0000 2",
            Mail = "jim.doe@test.com",
        };

        yield return new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = 3,
            SearchName = "Jack",
            CardNumber = "0000 0000 0000 0000 3",
            Mail = "jack.doe@test.com",
        };

        yield return new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = 4,
            SearchName = "Jane",
            CardNumber = "0000 0000 0000 0000 3",
            Mail = "john.doe@test.com",
        };

        yield return new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = 4,
            SearchName = "Joan",
            CardNumber = "0000 0000 0000 0000 3",
            Mail = "john.doe@test.com",
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query can be rewritten as:

```
var result = this.Context.Customers
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.SearchName, x.CardNumber })
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .OrderBy(x => x.SearchName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Created)
    .ToList();
```

You can see that the `.GroupBy(...)` call takes an expression of type `Expression<Func<Customer, TKey>>` where the `TKey` is an anonymous type. So if you can manage to generate the expression dynamically, then you can solve your problem.

I must admit that the anonymous type is created by the compiler, and therefore you do not have that type yet in your C# code.